# How does calling retain in different ways on the same object work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to know difference between following two:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[someObject returnMutableArray] retain];
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [someObject returnMutableArray];
[myArray retain];
```

I have some complex data flow project in which I have to return different NSMutableArrays.
I also want to know what is the best way to return NSMutableArrays.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference apart from how you want your code formatted.

The reason this works is in the documentation for [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retain)

> As a convenience, retain returns self because it may be used in nested expressions.

Therefore `retain` returns the object that is was called upon (a mutable array in your case) which means you can nest methods or simply use the return value in the assignment as you have in your example.

---

For returning values from methods you should make sure it is `autorelease`'d

So using your snippet

```
- (NSMutableArray *)myMethod;
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [someObject returnMutableArray];

    // ... do some work

    return myArray;
}
```

Because the method `returnMutableArray` does not contain the keyword's `alloc`, `new` or `copy` it should be made to return an `autorelease`'d object. Now as we are returning the object at the end of the method we don't need to take any further retains as it will be ready for returning.

If you are unsure on memory management you should read the [Advanced Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) or (preferably) start using ARC

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between 1 and 2.

The best practice on iOS is to return autoreleased objects from methods, and there should be no need to retain them.

If you are confused about how retain and release work, you should probably just enable ARC in your project, which manages retain and release for you automatically.